# Using Intent for android eclipse

Tags: android, android-intent

hi i have a layout.xml with 3 buttons linked to separate layouts.

i have managed to code for 1 button using intent. however, i do not know how to add in the next buttons so that they each go to a separate layout. this is my code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Activity1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button hello1, hello2, hello3;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            hello1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.hello1);
            hello2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.hello2);
                hello3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.hello3);
            hello1.setOnClickListener(this);
            hello2.setOnClickListener(this);
                hello3.setOnClickListener(this);             
        }

        public void onClick(View src) {
          Intent hello1 = new Intent(this, Hello1Activity.class);
          startActivity(hello1);         
          Intent hello2 = new Intent(this, Hello2Activity.class);
          startActivity(oltp);
              Intent hello3 = new Intent(this, Hello3Activity.class);
          startActivity(oltp);
        }
    }
```

this does not work at all.. the first button when clicked goes to hello3. if i remove the hello2 and hello3, then hello1 works well. any ideas please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've attached the same click-listener to all the three buttons and you are starting all the three activities in the onClick method. The Hello3 activity is the one that is started after Hello2Activity and Hello1Activity and hence it is always launched. To achieve what you are trying to do you should attach a different listener to every button and put the code specific to the button there. Something like:

```
    hello1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View src){
    Intent hello1 = new Intent(this, Hello1Activity.class);
          startActivity(hello1);  }
    });
```

Comment: thank you however, i would really appreciate if you could alter the code i have above with your answer as I have no clue where to place this.. appreciate if you could elaborate with my code. im lost sorry.

Comment: I've used your code to get it working for the first button. You can just copy this code and replace "1" with "2" and "3" to get it working for the other two buttons. You've to place this code in the onCreate method of your activity (wherever you have hello1.setOnClickListener(this) right now). Let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: thank you i tried but could not get it to work out.. it gives a forced error. i dont know how to show you the code here as i cannot fit it in. :(:(

Comment: i have tried various ways.. i guess i am putting the code in the wrong place. do u have an email please?

Comment: i tried this link, do you think it is better without onclicklistener?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755487/how-to-have-multiple-buttons-in-one-activity

Answer (score 0):

Since you set all 3 buttons onClickListener to `this` your `onClick` should look something like this:

```
public void onClick(View src) {
    switch(src.getId())
    {
    case R.id.hello1:
        Intent hello1Intent = new Intent(this, Hello1Activity.class);
        startActivity(hello1Intent);
        break;
    case R.id.hello2:
        Intent hello2Intent = new Intent(this, Hello2Activity.class);
        startActivity(hello2Intent);
        break;
    case R.id.hello3:
        Intent hello3Intent = new Intent(this, Hello3Activity.class);
        startActivity(hello3Intent);
        break;
    }
}
```

another solution is to have seperate onClickListener for each button.