# I can't make a new intent / activity from fragment that has 2 buttons

Tags: android, android-intent, android-button

I'm trying to make a new activity from a fragment that has 2 buttons. The button showed up on the emulator, but when I clicked it it doesn't do anything. I've followed many tutorials online but most of them do `onClickListener` on a single button. Sorry I'm new to android development.

```
public class UserFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    Activity context = getActivity();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);

        Button register = v.findViewById(R.id.btnAkunRegister);
        Button login = v.findViewById(R.id.btnAkunLogin);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnAkunLogin:
                Intent moveIntent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(moveIntent);
                break;

            case R.id.btnAkunRegister:
                moveIntent = new Intent(context, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(moveIntent);
                break;

        }

    }
}
```

update: I've tried following the answer from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4755545/10560523), but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: have you set `onClick` event in your xml ?

Comment: First case you are defining your Intent moveIntent but on second case you are not?

Comment: @MohammedHanif.no I haven't. How do I set it up? Which xml should I put the `onclick` event, the destination or the fragment I'm currently at?

Comment: @DanBaruch I've defined it at first, but it seems that I don't have to define it on the second case because it shows some error on android studio :/

Comment: Tbh, I'd just define it (and give it null value) before the switch case, and inside the switch just assign it's value and after the whole switch case, simply call startActivity with the intent, assuming it's not null, will save you some lines of codes

Comment: what the logcat says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `onClickListener` for your buttons. You implement this interface in you
Frgamnet, so you should set `this` as listener in your `onCreateView()` method.

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);

    Button register = v.findViewById(R.id.btnAkunRegister);
    Button login = v.findViewById(R.id.btnAkunLogin);
    //set listener
    register.setOnClickListener(this);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);
     
    return v;
}
```

Comment: I've tried it but the app suddenly closed. Here is the error on android studio :
[link](https://pastebin.com/UbJVVqwM) Sorry it's too long for me to paste it here so I make a pastebin file

Comment: It seems that changing the context variable in the intent method into `getActivity()` solves the problem! Thank you for telling me to set the `onClickListener()` method!